# How can I pass json data from onPostExecute to a fragment?

Tags: android

In my work i need to pass Json data from my onPostExecute() to a class that extends fragment . I have tried a lot by the following way but I am unable to get desired output....Please help me .
Here below code is from my onPostExecute()  :

```
else if(boollatlon==true){
        json_string=s;
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapFragment.class);
        //MapFragment.class is that class that extends Fragment
        intent.putExtra("json_data",json_string);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Here below is my MapFragment class :

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map_fragment,container,false);
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: I think maybe you should start from the beginning - by learning the ways of Android instead of deep-diving into something a little more complex like what you're trying to do. See for instance: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html
If you don't believe you need that, then you could try to invoke your `AsyncTask` from inside your `Fragment` by using an anonymous invocation of an `AsyncTask` where you override the `onPostExecute` inside the `Fragment` and hence make the data available directly. But take care, that you don't pass any context into the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call in the fragment in onCreateView next code:

```
String jsonData = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("json_data");
```

Answer (score 0):

When I see such a scenario, I think your best friend would be using Events. There are robust libraries like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) - my favorite.

You can add to your `build.gradle` file like this:

```
 compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

You can then create a simple plain old java object like this:

(I assume you are fetching your information from somewhere and that is why you have an AsyncTask)

```
public class FetchCompletedEvent{
    public String json;

    public FetchCompletedEvent(String json){
        this.json = json;
    }
}
```

Now, inside your `onPostExecute` method, you can notify the fragment of the event completion by using `EventBus` like this:

```
//inside onPostExecute()
String jsonString = result;
EventBus.getDefault().post(new FetchCompletedEvent(jsonString));
```

That is it for that part. Next is in your fragment class, do this:

```
//inside onAttach or onCreate of your fragment;
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

//now override onEvent method to handle the json String you will be given by the event

public void onEvent(FetchCompletedEvent event){

    //you could consider using a getter in your event class for this
    String json = event.json;
    //now you can update your UI with the new JSON data
}

//finally, unregister inside onDestroy
@Override public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy()
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

That, is all you need to pass your data to your fragment from inside onPostExecute method of your AsyncTask.

Events help decouple your code and eliminates too many dependencies - one of OOP grand principles!

I hope this helps! Good luck and happy coding!